# Bootstrapping multiple columns in data.table in a scalable fashion R

Tags: r, data.table, statistics-bootstrap

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913000/r-bootstrap-statistics-by-group-for-big-data) one. In the original question the OP wanted to perform bootstrap on two columns `x1` and `x2` that are fixed:

```
set.seed(1000)
data <- as.data.table(list(x1 = runif(200), x2 = runif(200), group = runif(200)>0.5))
stat <- function(x, i) {x[i, c(m1 = mean(x1), m2 = mean(x2))]}
data[, list(list(boot(.SD, stat, R = 10))), by = group]$V1
```

However, I think this problem can be nicely extended to handle any number of columns by treating them as groups. For instance, lets use the `iris` dataset. Say I want to calculate bootstrap mean for all four dimensions for each species. I can use melt to flip the data and then use the `Species`, `variable` combination to get the mean in one go - I think this approach will scale well.

```
data(iris)
iris = data.table(iris)
iris[,mean(Sepal.Length),by=Species]
iris[,ID:=.N,]
iris_deep = melt(iris
                 ,id.vars = c("ID","Species")
                 ,measure.vars = c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"))
#define a mean bootstrap function
stat <- function(x, i) {x[i, m=mean(value),]}
iris_deep[, list(list(boot(.SD, stat, R = 100))), by = list(Species,variable)]$V1
```

Here is my attempt at doing this. However the bootstrapping part does not seem to be working. As R throws the following error:

```
Error in mean(value) : object 'value' not found
```

Can someone please take a crack at this?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this (with added braces enclosing `m=mean(value)`) and it appears to work:

```
stat <- function(x, i) {x[i, (m=mean(value))]}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize each bootstrap fully, and calculate the mean for each variable within each group, instead of rerunning the bootstrap for each variable.

So if we do something like this, it calculates the mean for each variable:

```
iris = data.table(iris)
iris[sample(nrow(iris),replace=TRUE),lapply(.SD,mean,na.rm=TRUE),by=Species]
```

Because boot requires a vector / matrix output, we need to modify the output above, and provide names for the vector:

```
d = function(dat,ind){
 k = dat[ind,lapply(.SD,mean,na.rm=TRUE),by=Species]
 k_vec = unlist(k[,-1])
 names(k_vec) = paste(rep(colnames(k)[-1],each=nrow(k)),rep(k$Species,(ncol(k)-1)),sep="_")
 k_vec
}

d(iris,sample(nrow(iris),replace=TRUE))
 Sepal.Length_versicolor  Sepal.Length_virginica     Sepal.Length_setosa 
              5.8784314               6.4851852               4.9688889 
 Sepal.Width_versicolor   Sepal.Width_virginica      Sepal.Width_setosa 
              2.7392157               2.9814815               3.3977778 
Petal.Length_versicolor  Petal.Length_virginica     Petal.Length_setosa 
              4.1980392               5.5037037               1.4644444 
 Petal.Width_versicolor   Petal.Width_virginica      Petal.Width_setosa 
              1.2960784               2.0944444               0.2333333
```

And use boot with `strata = iris$Species` to ensure the Species are sampled evenly:

```
bo_strata = boot(iris,d,R=1000,strata=iris$Species)
```

We can compare the distributions of this approach compared to that in the question:

```
stat <- function(x, i) {x[i, (m=mean(value))]}
bo_melt = iris_deep[, list(list(boot(.SD, stat, R = 1000))), by = list(Species,variable)]$V1

par(mfrow=c(4,3))
par(mar=c(3,3,3,3))
for(i in 1:ncol(bo_strata$t)){
plot(density(bo_strata$t[,i]),main=names(bo_strata$t0)[i],col="#43658b")
lines(density(bo_melt[[i]]$t),col="#ffa372")
legend("topright",fill=c("#43658b","#ffa372"),c("strata","other"))
}
```

[image]